# Need a way to intercept only a Duplicate key exception in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, exception, unique-constraint, duplicate-data

Let's imagine that you have got a unique index constraint violation in your MSSQL 2008 database like this:

```
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_ManufacturerCode'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.ManufacturerCode'. The duplicate key value is (8410179)
```

Currently I am handling this exception by a global exception handler in a thick client (written in Delphi 6 using ADO, but it does not matter, I plan do use C#.NET in a future) and the exception message is appended to a log box.

But I want to handle this specific **duplicate key** exception personally and display an appropriate error message in a client using thick client's own text. I could parse the error message for match, but won't do this out of two reasons:

- This is not a right way to do the thing - it is better to rely on some error codes;
- The thick client is intended to use variety of MSSQL server versions in diverse languages which may have different error texts

It does not cheer me up to do the job with RETURNs with custom exit codes or constantly calling a special stored procedure to check for duplicates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ADO, you'd access the connections [`Errors`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms678380%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property after an error occurs, and examine the `NativeError` property to get the SQL Server specific error numbers.

When you switch to .NET, the same number is exposed as the `Number` property of [`SqlException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception.number.aspx) or [`SqlError`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlerror.aspx)

However, finding the specific error numbers can be a bit of a chore - For Duplicate Key, it's error number 2627.

Comment: Your answer seems good to me, but... could I detect this way which column violation occurred on?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/database-engine-events-and-errors?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, the only way to tell a duplicate key exception apart is to parse the error message.

A better solution is to prevent the duplicate key exception in the first place.  Write the insert not to insert duplicate keys, and check with `@@rowcount` if a row was added:

```
insert  YourTable
        (id, col1, col2)
select  1, 'a', 'b'
where   not exists
        (
        select  *
        from    YourTable yt2
        where   yt2.id = 1
        )

if @@rowcount = 0
    -- Duplicate key!
```

Comment: The question is rather about communication between MSSQL and thick client (the thing which comes when @@rowcount=0) than about how to detect duplicate key.

Comment: I interpreted your title `Need a way to intercept only a Duplicate key exception in MSSQL` as you only care about duplicate key exceptions. I think Andomar did to so you might want to rephrase the question.

Comment: Note that you'll want to manage locking correctly if there's any concurrent access to `YourTable`. It's possible that `@@rowcount` comes back zero just before someone else inserts the duplicate value into the table; code that assumes it's got the table locked for the next operation might not have done so, and will cause an error for the duplicate row which wasn't there when it happened to check.

Answer (score 3):

Fortunately, you don't have to parse the text. A `SqlException` has a `Number` property. Oberserve, what number is being returned and match on it. The numbers are well-defined. You can even look at all of them in one of the system catalog tables (don't have the name handy).

It is a very good idea of yours to catch only a very specific error instead of just catching all `SqlException`s (for example).

Comment: Your answer seems good to me, but... could I detect this way which column violation occurred on?

Comment: No, that unfortunately requires parsing the message. In general I would recommend that you only attempt to insert known-good data. Check before inserting. Handling errors as a response to bad data often is not the best strategy. Less control (as you are seeing here) and exceptions are extremely slow. It also feels backwards.

Comment: Yes, "Check before inserting" seems correct to me as well. Thanks, I really appreciate it...

Comment: Problem with "check before insert" is that it requires two roundtrips to the server and in the middle of them it becomes susceptible to race conditions. Just inserting and wait for the constraint to blow up solves both problems, at the cost of not being able to easily tell which was the duplicate when affecting more than one row.

Comment: @Alejandro that is true, it's a different trade-off. I have seen and done both ways of doing it and each has their place in my experience. You can check with MERGE in a single very slim operation, though, but that's probably still a little bit slower for small failure rates. The race is fixable through various means, as you surely know, but that has some (small) downsides as well.